# Android Studio NDK gradle: Cannot find share library

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm working on ffmpeg JNI with NDK in Android Studio. I've built ffmpeg with NDK outside of Android Studio, and put the libraries at src/main/jni/libs/armeabi-v7a.
 Next, I generated JNI head file and implement it with calling avformat API. However, the linker cannot find libavformat.so finally as below message.

"/Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld
Error:error: cannot find -lavformat"

Here is the build.gradle I made. I've added "avformat" into ldLibs, but it looks gradle doesn't know the lib path. I didn't find which gradle option could specify that. I'm using gradle distribution 3.3, while it has same problem with old gradle version 2.10.
 I appreciate any comment for this.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.example.com.ffmpegtestapp"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        ndk {
            moduleName "jnilib"
            ldLibs "log", "avformat"
            cFlags "-I${project.buildDir}/../src/main/jni/include"
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni']
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni/libs']
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just get working myself and share it here. I need create CMakeLists.txt to let cmake build and link native library for me, with external shared lib path specified.

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#create-cmake-script

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall")

add_library(jnilib SHARED
            native_lib.c)

target_include_directories(jnilib PRIVATE
                           ../include)

add_library(avformat SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(avformat PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libavformat.so)

target_link_libraries(jnilib
                      android
                      log
                      avformat)
```

The build.gradle is like this, with externalNativeBuild added.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.example.com.ffmpegtestapp"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        ndk {
            moduleName "jnilib"
            ldLibs "log", "avformat"
            cFlags "-std=c++11 -I${project.buildDir}/../src/main/jni/include"
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni']
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni/libs']
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path 'src/main/jni/src/CMakeLists.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

In addition of this, I found "undefined definition" error when linking libavformat.so, and finally I realized that I was using "native_lib.cpp" which is a C++ code trying to link C code.

```
error: undefined reference to 'avformat_version()'
```

It's resolved by rename native_lib.cpp to native_lib.c, or add external "C" for header files like this,

```
extern "C" {
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
}
```